# how do i make a Sencha Touch list display in a VBOX layout?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a main panel with layout set to vbox. I want to add TWO separate lists to the panel. I want the two lists to appear vertically stacked, and as they overflow the bottom of the main panel, the panel should simply scroll.

However, lists appear to require to be set in a FIT layout, in order to display. Fit layouts do not permit vertically stacking of items.

Am I missing a feature of the layout system that allows me to tell the list to fully display itself inside a parent with a vbox layout?

Answer (score 3):

`Ext.List` component's superclass is `Ext.DataView` and not `Ext.Panel`.

Hence, you will need to add two list in two separate panels and add those two panels inside a super panel.
Also, you will need to make the `layout:'vbox'` for the superpanel and make `layout:'fit'` for the other two child panels

Here's how you can do it.

```
....
....
var superpanel = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'vbox',             // to vertically stack two list.
    items: [
        {
           xtype: 'panel',
           id: 'panel_1',
           width: '100%',
           layout: 'fit',
           items: [
                {
                   xtype: 'list',
                   flex:1,
                   id: 'list1',
                   store: 'samplestore1'
                }
           ]
         },
         {
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'panel_2',
            width: '100%',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                 {
                  xtype: 'list',
                  id: 'list2',
                  flex:1,
                  store: 'samplestore2'
                 }
            ]
         }
    ]
 });
....
....
```

Comment: I don't think you need to nest each list in a wrapper panel. I quite happily put scrollable lists as first class children of vbox containers. Though if you are using vbox you should have a value for flex for each child unless docked.

Comment: Ahh! I missed that property. Applying `flex` will help the both the list to get equal space ...

Comment: i will double-check this, but i think that the flex solution makes each list take up exactly half the parent's height.  (leaving the list items to scroll within each list).  i would like each list to not scroll, and to full list their items.  i want the parent panel to scroll both the child lists, as vbox children.  (or will your solution do this?)

Comment: the answer is to leave the list items directly in the vbox, but put height:'auto' on the list rather than flex.

Answer (score 1):

```
var parent = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {
           xtype: 'list',
           id: 'list_1',
           store: 'store1,
           flex: 1
         },
         {
          xtype: 'list',
           id: 'list_2',
           store: 'store2,
           flex: 1
         }
    ]
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

put height:'auto' on the list item

```
items: [
    {
       xtype: 'list',
       height: 'auto'
     },
     {
      xtype: 'list',
       height: 'auto',
     }
]
```